# When I scroll for one time, it doesn't work for the second time, but it works for the third time,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I scroll for one time, it doesn't work for the second time, but it works for the third time, and so on
i have this function

```
  const scrollToElement = (id) => {
const element = document.getElementById(id);
if (element) {
  element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

};
this function get id from tag and scroll
and i have this code

```
  async function handleLength(input, name1, message) {
if (input == null || input.length === 0 || input == "انتخاب نشده") {
  setErrorF((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name1]: message }));
  scrollToElement(name1);
} else {
  setErrorF((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name1]: "" }));
}
```

}
when i called for one time function is good and scroll but when called for tow time not work and get this error in the console

```
Scroll anchoring was disabled in a scroll container because of too many consecutive adjustments (10) with too little total distance (-0.659999990463257 px average, -6.6 px total).
```